# Linker Script Does Not Skip Bytes As Expected

Tags: assembly, x86, ld, linker-scripts, objcopy

So, I have this assembly file, which I assemble with GNU as and link with GNU ld using a linker script.

Linker script (`boot.ld`):

```
INPUT(boot.o)
OUTPUT(boot.out)
ENTRY(boot_start)

SECTIONS {
        . = 0x7c00;
        .text : { *(.text) }
        .data : { *(.data) }
        . = 0x7dfe;
        .boot_end : { *(.boot_end) }
}
```

As you see I try to make the file exactly 512 bytes as needed for a bootloader by doing `. = 0x7cdfe`. `.boot_end` contains the boot signature and thus fills up the remaining two bytes.

I create the bootloader as follows:

```
m4 boot.S | as -o boot.o
ld -T boot.ld
objcopy -O binary boot.out boot.img
```

`boot.out` contains the sections already with absolute addresses and everything seems fine. `.boot_end` is at `0x7dfe` and I expect the holes to be filled with zeros, but no, `boot.img` is a total of 55 bytes. The, for me, weird thing is that the file does not even contain the boot signature. It's just `.text` and `.data` without either `.boot_end` or the skipped bytes.

How do I move ld to skip those bytes? And where is my boot signature gone?

Comment: What section names did you use for the missing parts and what flags did you set (what do you feed into `as`) ? Whether you use ELF or COFF or whatever object format can also matter.

Comment: @tofro `.boot_end` is the section I'm missing and I assembled with `as` just like written in my question. I use ELF.

Comment: And you still didn't say what `.section` flags you give in `as` code. Point is, if no section flags are given to `as` in ELF for a non-standard (not `.text` or `.data` or the like) section name, the section will not be allocated. Try to replace your (presumably) naked `.section boot_end` directive in `as` input with `.section boot_end,"a"` (or more flags, for example to make it executable, depending on what you need) and try again.

Comment: @tofro Oh, OK, I'll try.

Comment: @tofro Thanks very much, it did work. I tried with `.section .boot_end "", @progbits` first, but the result was the same. I tried again with `.section .boot_end "a", @progbits`, just for the sake of it, and it worked. The thing is `a` indicates allocatable sections, which `.boot_end` is not. Any thoughts on which flag I could use? And why won't GNU as generate data for custom sections without flags?

Comment: @tofro Also, I am using `.boot_end` just because I didn't find any other way to place user-defined data at a physical address in the linker script. I want to stay independent of other sections, so I didn't simply place the boot signature in `.data`. Creating a new section and placing it at the end seemed the only viable solution. Is there a simpler, more straightforward way to place data in an executable at a certain location?

Comment: You can place a boot signature in the linker script with something like 
`.boot_end : AT(0x7DFE) {
    SHORT(0xaa55);
}`

Comment: You might mis-understand *allocatable* - That just says "goes into the image" in ELF terminology. That method is allright for placing stuff at specific addresses, so "a" is fine. Actually, it's `objcopy` that was made to exclude non-allocatable sections from the image dump. Why they did that is both beyond my knowledge and my understanding. I'd rather have a flag in a section if you *don't* want it to go into the image (maybe because you only want it to resolve I/O addresses)

Comment: @MichaelPetch I saw it in your answer and tried it, but it somehow gave a syntax error. I'm going to try it again later, maybe I mistyped something.

Comment: @tofro Alright, I understand, thanks. Feel free to write an answer and enjoy some additional rep.

Comment: I removed the answer because of a technical inaccuracy when I first typed it up and then realized it really didn't answer the question. Was better to delete it than keep it around. Although you should still be able to use _SHORT_ to output a 16-bit word to a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are most probably missing a section flag. Point is, if no section flags are given to `as` when you are later linking to ELF for a non-standard (not `.text` or `.data` or the like) section name, the section will not be allocated in the dump (i.e, silently be ignored by `objcopy`, note that this behaves differently when producing `coff` files)

Try to replace your (presumably) naked

```
.section boot_end
```

directive in your assembler input file with

```
.section boot_end,"a"
```

(or more flags, for example to make it executable, depending on what you need) and try again.

The "a" flag makes the section *allocatable*, i.e. tells both `ld` and `objcopy` you want it in your binary.